# Scala interview task

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. I have come across this Scala program and it was asked in interview.

What is the output of the following program

```
object ApplyTo extends Application { 
  val k = "gWU`UAXYjT[ig\\\\eBWca"; 
  println(k map {c => (c - k.size).toChar toLower}) 
}
```

Please help. I am very new to Scala. I am also not sure that this program will even compile or not.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: The question is stupid. I don't doubt there is someone who know the ascii table by hearth, but what's the value of it?  Better would've been to have some simple arithmetic test or something that could be answered. With this is like *"Ok, I have character g, what's g ascii value subtracted 20 ? ..."*

Comment: @OscarRyz I think the real question is whether you know what the map function does, but yeah memorization of the ascii table is ridiculous and useless on the whole.

Comment: That's right, but if you get asked *What's the output..* you can't say: well I don't know but what it does is... I mean is stupid.

Comment: If that interview question comes up again, ask for a printed ASCII table.

Comment: "Compile-time error. Oh wait, the Scala libraries are busted. Actually, I don't care." If this is a good answer to you, I want to work with you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The output is `scala-dev@gushhq.com`

Map applies an operation to every member of an iterable. In this case for every character in the string k, the length of the string is subtracted (in this case 20). When you subtract an int from a char you get an Int which is why toChar is needed. Finally toLower ensures that the output is all lowercase. It seems they are just testing whether you are comfortable with the map function, since the rest is pretty straightforward (assuming they don't want you to memorize ascii codes...)

Also, one of the best features of scala is the interactive console, you may want to try it :)